# Connection to the notebook server cannot be established

Tags: python, jupyter

I used to work with Jupyter notebook normally, but after formatting my laptop and reinstall it again, notebooks take a lot of time to be charged and the connection to the notebook server cannot be established.

Also when I look at my cmd, I recognize that Jupyter tries to call some libraries which are not in this particular notebook I opened, for example, the Cose library which I used in another notebook which I didn't even open after the installation!

[image]

And I always get the following message on my notebook:

> Connection to the notebook server cannot be established. The notebook will continue its attempts. Check your network connection or the settings of the notebook server.

So what should I do, I really need your help and I will be so thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options:

1. You can try installing `cose` module - it shows `ModuleNotFoundError`. Probably when you reformatted your laptop, the library could have been uninstalled.
2. You can try re-installing conda and jupyter notebook

Comment: 1 - I don't need cose module in my notebook! normally it should call it just if I imported it in my notebook but I didn't

 2 - I uninstalled the following ones before : 

ipykernel
ipython
jupyter_client
jupyter_core
traitlets
ipython_genutils

then I re-installed it again but always the same problem!

Comment: Hey, I installed the cose package even if I thought it's not the solution and yeah it works now which is really strenge for me, I thought it was giving me the message just because I used that module in another notebook not the one I try to open, thank you